# Kubernetes can't access loadbalancer url using minikube - nopcommerce

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, minikube, kubernetes-pod, nopcommerce

To get some more experience with hosting kubernetes clusters I created a nopcommerce deployment. For the service I use the loadbalancer type.

Running the command `minikube service nopcommerce --url`
gives me the url http://192.168.76.2:30409. I'm not able to connect to this url. The verbose log using curl prints:

> curl -L http://192.168.76.2:30409 --verbose
>
> - Trying 192.168.76.2:30409...
> - Connected to 192.168.76.2 (192.168.76.2) port 30409 (#0)
>   GET / HTTP/1.1
>   Host: 192.168.76.2:30409
>   User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
>   Accept: */*
> - Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
> - Closing connection 0
>   curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

My `kustomization.yaml`:

```
secretGenerator:
- name: mysql-pass
  literals:
  - password='VerySecretPassword'
resources:
  - mysql.yaml
  - nopcommerce.yaml
```

And the `nopcommerce.yaml`:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nopcommerce
  labels:
    app: nopcommerce
spec:
  selector:
    app: nopcommerce
    tier: app
  ports:
    - port: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nopcommerce
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nopcommerce
      tier: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nopcommerce
        tier: app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nopcommerce
          image: nopcommerceteam/nopcommerce:latest
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: web
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that the host of the deployed api was wrong and had to be bind to `0.0.0.0` to match `localhost`. This is a simple example of a successful deployment with minikube:

Preliminary step is to install minikube and run `minikube start`; then

```
# simpleapi/app.py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def hello_world():
    return {"hello": "world"}
```

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.10-slim

COPY . .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Bind to port 5000
EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["uvicorn", "simpleapi.app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "5000"]
```

```
# requirements.txt 
anyio==3.6.2
click==8.1.3
fastapi==0.94.1
h11==0.14.0
idna==3.4
pydantic==1.10.6
sniffio==1.3.0
starlette==0.26.1
tomli==2.0.1
typing_extensions==4.5.0
uvicorn==0.21.1
```

```
# kubernetes-deploy.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: simpleapi-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: simpleapi-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: simpleapi-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: simpleapi-app
        image: {dockerhub-username}/simpleapi:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

where `dockerhub-username` is the dockerhub username for pushing the image. To deploy

```
# Compile the dockerfile
docker build -t simpleapi:latest .

# re-tag for pushing to docker hub (add username/{containername})
docker tag simpleapi:latest {dockerhub-user}/simpleapi:latest

# push to docker hub
docker push {dockerhub-user}/simpleapi:latest

# create kube deployment
kubectl apply -f kubernetes-deploy.yaml

# expose deployment
kubectl expose deployment simpleapi-deployment --type=LoadBalancer --port=5000
```

Finally run `minikube tunnel` in another terminal.

```
kubectl get svc
```

will show the external IP for `curl`.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following methods:

Troubleshoot:
Try running other apps that can connect to the same server from your system.

SSL:
If the URL is with HTTPS; not configuring proper SSL settings leads to error in the old version of curl.
The remote server may have firewall settings enabled so, you need to check for the other libraries that are installed and are in conflict with the service.

Upgrade all packages:
“Connection reset by peer”, is caused by outdated packages and you need to remove unnecessary ones and check for the similar ones.

Timeout:
There is a timeout from the server site that is establishing connection before handshake.